# Override calculated value with event

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Edit: I have several forms which calculate mathematical functions which display the results in the respective output fields. My problem is, occasionally, I need to override the calculated result with a value.

e.g. if the calcualted value for f4 is 40, I'd like the field to show 33.5 instead.

How I can I achieve this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<form onsubmit="return false" onclick="f4.value= (parseFloat(4)*parseFloat(c.value))  ">

<input id="c" name="c" value="10" type="radio">
  10
<input id="f4">
```

And for the javascript:

```
function writeF4() {

if (f4==40) {document.getElementById("f4").value = 33.5;}
}

document.getElementById("c").addEventListener('click', writeF4);
```

I assume, the reason this doesn't work is because I have 40 for f4 as well as 33.5.

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117011/discussion-on-question-by-notreallyashark-if-value-is-x-then-display-y).

Answer (score 0):

The function you want to apply takes two inputs: `t` and `c`, and produces four outputs `f1, f2, f3, f4`. Internally to the function, we have some special cases, which we can handle by checking the values and replacing them as a second step.

This code is optimised for step-by-step readability, not for performance or brevity, but it should do the job and is pretty clear (I think):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4L6mf0kk/

HTML:

```
<table id="input-options">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>T</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="t1" name="t" type="radio" value="9.58333" checked="true" /><label for="t1">t1</label></td>
      <td><input id="c1" name="c" type="radio" value="12" checked="true"/><label for="c1">12</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="t2" name="t" type="radio" value="7.50" /><label for="t2">t2</label></td>
      <td><input id="c2" name="c" type="radio" value="24" /><label for="c2">24</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<dl id="output-values">
  <dt>f1:</dt>
  <dd id="f1-value"></dd>
  <dt>f2:</dt>
  <dd id="f2-value"></dd>
  <dt>f3:</dt>
  <dd id="f3-value"></dd>
  <dt>f4:</dt>
  <dd id="f4-value"></dd>
</dl>
```

Javascript:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------
// 1: Collect up our input and output elements

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#input-options input'),
    outputs = {
      f1: document.querySelectorAll('#f1-value')[0],
      f2: document.querySelectorAll('#f2-value')[0],
      f3: document.querySelectorAll('#f3-value')[0],
      f4: document.querySelectorAll('#f4-value')[0]      
    };

// ------------------------------------------------------
// 2: Calculate function
// This takes two input numbers and returns an object with 4 values

var calculate = function(t, c) {
  //These are the modifiers that we use on each return value:
  var modifiers = {
    f1: 240,
    f2: 525,
    f3: 570,
    f4: 390
  },
  results = {}; //This object collects the results of the calculation

  //Do each of the calculations on your values:
  Object.keys(modifiers).forEach(function(key) {
    results[key] = Math.round((t + modifiers[key]/c)*100)/100;
  });

  //Now, specify any 'special' override rules
  if (results['f4'] == 40) {results['f4'] = 33.5} //If f4 equals 40, switch it to 33.5 instead

  //Pass back the result object
  return results;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------
// 3: Update Function
// Update the DOM with the output of the calculation, based on the currently selected options

var update = function() {
  //Collect the selected values:
  var t = parseFloat(document.querySelectorAll('#input-options input[name=t]:checked')[0].value),
      c = parseFloat(document.querySelectorAll('#input-options input[name=c]:checked')[0].value);

  //Grab the results of the calculation:
  var values = calculate(t, c); 

  //Apply them to the output elements:
  Object.keys(values).forEach(function(key) {
    outputs[key].innerHTML = values[key];
  });
}

// ------------------------------------------------------
// 4: Assign an event listener to each input so it calls the update function when changed

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', update);
}
```

One pattern I've used here is to use a hash wherever we're dealing with `f1, f2, f3, f4` - the values, the results, and the HTML elements that display the values. That way, we can loop through the hash, and know that `f1` in the results hash can be inserted into `f1` in the output elements hash. It also makes it clear and easy if you had to extend the calculation with other values.

I know this doesn't take into account all your special rules, but hopefully it's clear how to extend it to include them.

Comment: Also, if you happen to have jQuery or underscore available, this could be made a lot more compact.